# Carregar Google Maps sem internet - Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Estou criando um app utilizando a activity padrão do google maps no android studio, a aplicação já está completa, porém gostaria que ela funcionasse sem internet, vi que o app do google maps tem essa funcionalidade, mas ainda não vi nenhuma aplicação de terceiros fazendo isso, é possível? Alguém tem alguma informação a respeito?

Comment: Imagino que tenha que fazer o download do mapa para o dispositivo, veja se isso ajuda: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá para você fazer isso usando uma classe chamada `TileProvider`, que trata de criar uma coleção de imagens exibida sobre os blocos do mapa básico. Sendo assim, aí vai da criatividade, você pode gravar na memória do dispositivo ou num cartão SD em formato .ZIP. Desta forma, você pode criar uma lógica para toda vez que não houver internet, consultar este bloco de imagens para reconstruir o mapa.

> Uma [`TileOverlay`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay.html?hl=pt-br) define uma coleção de imagens adicionada sobre os
>   blocos do mapa básico. Também é possível usar sobreposições de blocos
>   para adicionar recursos ao mapa, fornecendo imagens de bloco
>   transparentes. É necessário fornecer os blocos para cada nível de zoom
>   que você pretende oferecer. Se você tiver blocos suficientes em
>   diversos níveis de zoom, poderá complementar os dados de mapa da
>   Google para o mapa completo.

#### Exemplo:

```
GoogleMap map; // ... declara um mapa
TileProvider tileProvider; // ... cria um tile provider
TileOverlay tileOverlay = map.addTileOverlay(
     new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

Chamando o `GoogleMap.addTileOverlay()`:

```
TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
  @Override
  public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {

    /* Define the URL pattern for the tile images */
    String s = String.format("http://my.image.server/images/%d/%d/%d.png",
        zoom, x, y);

    if (!checkTileExists(x, y, zoom)) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      return new URL(s);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }

  /*
   * Check that the tile server supports the requested x, y and zoom.
   * Complete this stub according to the tile range you support.
   * If you support a limited range of tiles at different zoom levels, then you
   * need to define the supported x, y range at each zoom level.
   */
  private boolean checkTileExists(int x, int y, int zoom) {
    int minZoom = 12;
    int maxZoom = 16;

    if ((zoom < minZoom || zoom > maxZoom)) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
};

TileOverlay tileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
    .tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

Esta imagem descreve um pouco o que acontece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> A Google Maps API divide as imagens de cada nível de zoom em um
>   conjunto de blocos de mapa quadrados, organizados em uma grade. Quando
>   um mapa muda para uma nova localização ou para um novo nível de zoom,
>   a Maps API determina quais blocos são necessários e converte essa
>   informação em um conjunto de blocos a recuperar.

Existe um projeto [OSMDROID](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) que suporte para Java nativo para Android e para Xamarim, que já é um empurrão pra você trabalhar com Mapa offline. Dê uma lida mais para saber a respeito e instale o aplicativo de [Mapas e Navegação — OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand&referrer=utm_source%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_medium%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_campaign%3DAndroidPIT) para você ter mais noção do funcionamento.

#### Detalhes

- [Sobreposição de blocos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay?hl=pt-br)
- [Coordenadas e Projeções](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/theory/concepts/coordinates-docpage/)
- [Exemplos de uso do MapTileProviderBasic](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic)
- [Como usar a biblioteca osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library)

Comment: Perfeito Cleidimar, ótimas informações, vou dar início ao estudo, obrigado.